# Page preloader before page load jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, loader

I am totally new in jQuery. I am trying to show a loader before all my page content is ready.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        console.log('wait');
        $("#wait").css("display", "block").show();
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $("#wait").css("display", "none").hide();
    });
});
```

and in body i have this,

```
<div id="wait" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:20%;left:50%;"><img src="{{ asset('assets/global/img/ajax-loader.gif') }}" /></div>
```

but no loader is displayed and no error shows in console.
Can anyone give me any solution or example regarding this?

Thank in advance!

Comment: If this is just for when you first open the page (or refresh it), remove `display:none` from the style attribute so it's visible immediately.  If the `ajaxComplete()` handler is working then that should be all you need.  Also, if you're setting the `display` value then you can remove the `.show()` and `.hide()` as that's what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Demo Code Below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#loader').fadeOut(showBodyPart);
  

  function showBodyPart(){
   $('#body_parts').fadeIn(300);
  }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KUJoe.gif" id="a" alt="Loading" />
     Loading...
</div>

<div id="body_parts" style="display: none;">
 <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
 <p>Click me away!</p>
 <p>Click me too!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome @TahmidSaim brother.

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 4, Jquery, CSS

```
<style>
 .overlay {
    position: absolute; background-color: white; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto; z-index: 10;
}
    .overlay div{ position: relative; z-index: 10; top:30%; left: 50%;}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="spinner-border text-secondary" >
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div> Helloo World</div>
</body>
```

JQuery

```
<script>
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $( ".overlay" ).fadeOut(100, function() {
        $( ".overlay" ).remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).